# if we separate the class declaration and its implementation into two files, how to compile them without IDE?

Tags: c++

I was recommended to separate the class implementation from its declaration. For example, fish.h for class declaration while fish.cpp for class implementation. but the question is that I can only include fish.h in the file which contains main function. IDE can solve this problem by making them into one project, but I wonder how to do it without IDE in VS compiler? Suppose we have three files:

fish.h for class declaration;

fish.cpp for class implementation;

test.cpp contains the main function;

(I use cl /EHsc test.cpp for single file compilation before)

Comment: Did you try something like `cl /EHsc test.cpp fish.cpp`?

Comment: Have you just tried adding the second source file when building?

Comment: ok, you are right, thank all of you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IDE isn't in charge of compilation.

Behind the scenes, there's a different program.
The building process is done in 2 steps:

- *Compilation* - generating intermediate binaries for each translation unit (`.cpp` files).
- *Linking* - going through all binaries, connecting the dots, and making a single binary (`.exe`).

The IDE automagically keeps track of which files to feed the building toolchain. Nothing prevents you from doing it yourself.

Armed with this knowledge - you know to give the compiler `.cpp` files, and the linker `.h` files + whatever the compiler spits out.

Comment: Depends on the IDE.   Some IDEs have pretty tight integration of compiler and linker.